# R (data.table) computing mean after two merges with massive datasets

Tags: r, merge, data.table, bigdata

I have three datasets, two of which two are massive. Dataset 1 informs multiple values of `y` for a given `x`. Dataset 2 informs multiple values of `w` for a given `y`. Finally, dataset 3 informs a single `z` for each `w`.

I would like to compute the average value of `z` for each `x`. The simplest way would be to, first, merge `DT_xy` with `DT_yw` (using `y` as key variable) to then merge it with `DT_wz` (using `w` as key variable) to, finally, compute the mean of `z` for every `x`. I show the code below for this.

I am looking for a more efficient code, given that `DT_xy` is already massive. Merging it with `DT_yw` increases its rows by 1000 which is unfeasible. I don't need to know the individual values of `w` for every `x`-`y`. I just need to know average `z` for each `x`.

```
DT_xy = data.table(x=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,13)), y=(c(1:10, 1:13)))
DT_yw = data.table(y=rep(1:13,200), w=1:13*200)
DT_wz = data.table(w=1:13*200, z=1000:2600)

data_merge1 <- DT_yw[DT_xy, on="y", allow.cartesian = TRUE]
data_merge2 <- DT_wz[data_merge1, on="w", allow.cartesian = TRUE]

output <- data_merge2[, mean(z), by="x"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this more efficiently, by collapsing `DT_wz` into the mean and row count of `z` by `w`, and collapsing `DT_yw` into the rowcount by `w` and `y`, and generate row_count weighted means.. This avoids any cartesian joins

```
wz = DT_wz[, .(.N, mean(z)),w]
yw = DT_yw[, .N, .(y,w)]
f <- function(df) df[, sum(N*V2*i.N)/sum(N*i.N)]
yw[DT_xy, on="y"][wz, on="w"][, f(.SD),x]
```

Output:

```
   x       V1
1: 1 1798.802
2: 2 1800.000
```